# Saving String with Decimal Number from JSON as Number(Uint) without Losing Decimals

Tags: string

Hey Im trying to use an exchange rate gathered from json as a string to create a uint variable similar to the rate, but I need a way to capture the information after the decimal. For instance I want "1.45" to end up as "145" or something similar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Decide how many decimal places you want and multiply by that number. That way your contract can work in uints internally. At Reality Keys we publish data like this:

https://www.realitykeys.com/exchange/11353
(Look under "See how we will sign".)

Alternatively the Solidity docs mention a `real` type.

Comment: This isn't useful without some way to import the number from the string to an uint. Like how do I multiple "1.45" as a string by 100 for instance then save it as a uint.

I need some way to parse the string will retaining the .45.

Comment: Where is this string coming from in the first place? Why are you passing a string into your contract when you want it to have a number?

Comment: If you're getting the data from Oraclize then they have a function that looks like it multiplies it out. https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol#L254 It would make more sense to do it before you send it to the contract though, not sure if that's something they can do for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was using Oraclize. They do indeed have one, which I just recently discovered. Do you know another simple way to get external data into contracts beside Oraclize?

Comment: There are a few options for exchange rates right now depending what you need: 1) There are people pushing data to contracts which you can read directly. 2) Pulling from some URL with Oraclize. 3) Get signed data from Reality Keys, send it to the contract in your DApp.